# Xamarin.Forms MasterDetail Vs Navigation Issues

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created the application with iPad, Android Tablets, using Navigation and MasterDetail approach Lemme explain the application scenario like below:

> First page contains the login form so I navigated the login page from the Main page like below.

```
public App()
{
// The root page of your application

var nav = new NavigationPage(new LoginViewController());
nav.BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#EEEEEE");
nav.BarTextColor = Color.FromHex("#424242");
MainPage = nav;

}
```

> Now, once the user has done the login activity I want to move the app into home screen like below.

```
async void OnButtonClickedLogin(object sender, EventArgs args)
{

// As per having some REST call in this I made this method as async

HomeViewController test = new HomeViewController();
await test.loadTopLoan_Datas();
await this.Navigation.PushAsync(test);

}
```

> Now the home screen contains the list of details by List View. So once user tapping the list item I wanna move the next screen as a MasterDetail page like below.

```
listView.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
{

Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new LeadViewController()));

}
```

> So the above action move the leadViewController Master detail page in this working fine in a tablet but while I'm running the build in Android tablet it's mentioned the error as below that:
>
> Attaching LeadViewController Master Detail Page Source below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace eMO_Xamarin
{
public class LeadViewController : MasterDetailPage
{

public static INavigation Navi
{
get;
set;
}

public LeadViewController()
{
this.BackgroundImage = "Bg6.jpg";

NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(this, "");
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

this.Title = "Lead section";

var menuPage = new MenuPage();
menuPage.OnMenuSelect = (categoryPage) =>
{

Detail = new NavigationPage(categoryPage);

if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
{

IsPresented = false;

}
else if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
{

IsPresented = true;

}

else {
IsPresented = true;
}
};

Master = menuPage;

var letsGetPage = new NavigationPage(new LetsGetStartedPage());
Detail = letsGetPage;
MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Default;

}
}
}
```

> Android only allows one navigation page

So, In this case, how can I manage this scenario well in the iOS as well Android platform. How can I manage the masterDetail page scenario from existing Navigation push?

Comment: Navigation.PushModalAsync(Page page) ist your friend. Android has only one NavigationContext per NavigationPage so you need to create one by calling PushModal.

Comment: Hi @BenediktSchroeder - After I changed Main page to login page calling as below : `LoginViewController loginVC = new LoginViewController(); MainPage = loginVC;` and HomePage to MasterDetail Page as `LeadViewController leadVC = new LeadViewController(); Navigation.PushModalAsync(leadVC);` and Finally I changed the MasterDetails behavior like below : `Master = menuPage;
var letsGetPage = new NavigationPage(new LetsGetStartedPage());
Detail = letsGetPage;
MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Default;`

Comment: Getting this error log while launching MasterDetailPage from home screen: `Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 4365 (GpuThread)`